# I lose WSOAuth20Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, websphere, access-token

I am using OAuth2 in Websphere 8.0.0.5. I get an access token and make a link. For example: https://IP:PORT/wps/myportal/PATH/?access_token=CARN1QbcWYUfT9kL1yZ13hOxXV0S5G0PNHRwDs22. When a I click in this link, I access OK and I can to get the token. But, in the second intent I lose the token.

Example:

1) Access to generate an access token

```
Asunto:
Sujeto: defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/userapp
Credencial pública: com.ibm.ws.security.auth.WSCredentialImpl@a60840bf
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@6b291942
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@bdc2e900
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@e2b283b9
```

2) Generated link with access token

```
https://IP:10029/wps/myportal/PATH/?access_token=spPHk7MMBsianOvLI9yLYFepIpXyBkj5lghoWp6J
```

3) Click in link - First intent

```
Asunto:
Sujeto: defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin
Credencial pública: com.ibm.ws.security.auth.WSCredentialImpl@5110eb9e
Credencial privada: Provider:OAuthProvider,user:wasadmin,client:user,expiration:Mon Jul 10 16:06:53 ART 2017,token:spPHk7MMBsianOvLI9yLYFepIpXyBkj5lghoWp6J,
Credencial privada: {OAuthProvider=OAuthProvider, com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.cacheKey=OAuthProvider-692974521}
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@11ebdd0c
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@caf4f5f9
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@5ed614f8
```

4) Click in link - Second intent

```
Asunto:
Sujeto: defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin
Credencial pública: com.ibm.ws.security.auth.WSCredentialImpl@a64eaabc
Credencial privada: {com.ibm.wsspi.security.cred.cacheKey=OAuthProvider-692974521, OAuthProvider=OAuthProvider}
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.SingleSignonTokenImpl@39d13d7d
Credencial privada: com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthenticationTokenImpl@c38fb578
Credencial privada:    com.ibm.ws.security.token.AuthorizationTokenImpl@738fd8aa
```

Any help?

ERA

Comment: Access tokens might be short-lived. Maybe you hit the token timeout. Compare the `  Provider:OAuthProvider,user:wasadmin,client:user,expiration:Mon Jul 10 16:06:53 ART 2017...`

Comment: But in the second intent I can to access to the page... If the token was expired, I think that I shouldn't to access...

Comment: Can The token have some special configuration about this situation?